# How do I "install" a program once I compile it, so I can run it from the command line?

Tags: linux, archlinux

Archlinux.

I downloaded **mtools**, which includes **mcopy**, which is what I'm after. The instructions in the INSTALL file say do this:

```
# ./configure
# make
```

These worked fine, now I have a bunch of `.o` files and of course executables.

What do I need to do, so I can just type

```
# mcopy
```

and have it run? Since I don't have it "installed" right now, doing that just says

```
-bash: mcopy: command not found
```

Comment: You just need to put `mcopy` in a directory that's in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Is there a make install command in the makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual linux build sequence is

```
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
```

`make check` attempts to validate if the build took place correctly; not all Makefiles have it but many do. Note you will need `sudo make install` to do the install in the usual system directories if you are not root.

You can determine which of these options is available for your particular Makefile by

```
cat Makefile
```

and reading the labels on the left of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a symbolic link to the application in your /usr/bin folder like

```
ln -s /fullpath/to/app /usr/bin/aliasnameforapp
```

Then you can simple call `aliasnameforapp` from anywhere.